# How can I place images on the terrain in SC2 maps?

Tags: modding, starcraft-2

I have seen [this video where there are logos of the clans rendered on the ground](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnEcfKevJXY#t=29) in StarCraft 2.

How can I add images of my own in a custom map?

Comment: Game specific mod questions are typically better asked on forums for those games. Those questions usually don't get a good response here.

Answer (score 1):

[According to that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qnEcfKevJXY#t=60), it's a feature of that specific overlay client, not a feature of Starcraft II, so it cannot be done.

Comment: i know it is, the video is just a demonstration for what i am heading for - everything is possible in the starcraft 2 editor

Comment: @daniel: I don't know what you mean, *"everything is possible in the starcraft 2 editor,"* because what you're asking for is not possible.